# Compare two String Types?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I am trying to compare two strings. But this is where I do not understand.

First String comes from a URLSession. What I am doing is, convert incoming data of URLSession, to String using,

```
let phpResponse = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8);
```

And Now I need to compare this string with Plain String which is,

```
let isWhat = "Success";
```

But when I try to compare them using `==`operator, it says strings are not similar. Actually these two variables shows the same content when I print them into Console.

Then I tried to find the types of these two variables using `type(of:)` operator and both variables were `String`. I'm not sure what I am missing here. Can someone help me? Why it says that these two Strings are not same?

Comment: That's kind of weird, post the screenshot.

Comment: `print(data as NSData)` where `data` is the var to create `phpResponse` and `print(isWhat.htmlStr.data(using: .utf8) as NSData)` It may point out the issue.

Comment: @Larme it says "Variable of type String has no member htmlStr"

Comment: Bad copy paste sorry, I meant: `print(isWhat.data(using: .utf8) as NSData)`

Comment: @Larme It shows some characters inside optional.

Comment: Could you show us both printed values?

Comment: @Larme Why NSData instead Data?

Comment: @Kevinosaurio Because the `description` of `NSData` object is often more useful than the one of `Data` version. Try this `let myStr = "myStr";
let data = myStr.data(using: .utf8); print("data: \(data!)"); print("data as NSData: \(data as! NSData)");` in Playground, you'll see: `data: 5 bytes
data as NSData: <6d795374 72>`

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your kind help. There was a hidden line breaker included in PHP response. Because of lots of debugging prints, I missed it. Thanks again. Now it works.

Comment: @Larme Ohhh right ty.

Comment: `print(string.debugDescription)` can also help.

Comment: String may contain some unprintable characters like suggested word breaks or http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2063/index.htm . Try checking the UTF characters of both strings using "string.unicodeScalars"